# jquery working in jsfiddle, but not on site

Tags: jquery, html-lists, jsfiddle

I know people have submitted similar questions, but I've been through the answers as well and not seen a solution that works. I wrote a script that sorts my list of portfolio items in jsfiddle. It looks something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".music-button" ).click(function() {
      $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.music').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
      $('.music').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

 )};
```

On jsfiddle, the script works, but when I plug it into my site's footer, it does not do a thing. Would anyone know why?

I've put everything (stylesheet and all) into jsfiddle, and my site works: http://jsfiddle.net/LbgPF/2/

But when I go to my actual website, my script does not work: http://www.rileydra.com/00_dra/work/branding-and-identity/

I've spent quite a bit of time on this but still think the solution is something simple that I'm overlooking.

**Edit:** changed the script excerpt to better show the error of my ways.

Comment: I see exactly the same results in jsfiddle and on the site linked.

Comment: It's never a good sign when you have multiple functions that perform the same action for different elements, you should be able to abstract it using a common class for your elements, also next time some javascript is not working look at your browser's console, all errors are logged there, right now you're getting `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function` which you can fix with @Arun's answer

Comment: I just noticed that error in firebug. And I did initially have it as just one function, but thought that might be what's causing the problem. Now that you got things working, it's going to go back as a single expression.

Comment: Good, one more thing, you should add `e.preventDefault()` in your function to prevent the default action when clicking the anchor links because right now it scrolls the page to the top

Comment: Ha. Dear lord, that was exactly was I was looking up how to do. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) in your page, so `$` does not point to jQuery. so instead of using `$` in your script you need to use `jQuery`.

Change the script in sort.js to

```
//here the shortcut version of dom ready is used, also the jQuery instance is passed as a parameter to the callback function which we assigns to a local parameter $, so we can use $ to refer jQuery inside the callback method
jQuery(function($){

    $( ".technology-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.technology').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.technology').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".retail-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.retail').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.retail').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".real-estate" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.real-estate').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.real-estate').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".publishing-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.publishing').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.food').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".music-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.music').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.music').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".churches-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.churches').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.churches').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".health-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.health').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.health').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".food-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.food').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.food').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".finance-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.finance').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.finance').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".entertainment-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.entertainment').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.entertainment').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".education-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').not('.education').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible');
        $('.education').addClass('visible').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $( ".all-button" ).click(function() {
        $('.project-thumb-inside').addClass('visible');
        $('.project-thumb-inside').removeClass('hidden');
    });

});
```

Comment: I could kiss you right now. Thank you. This solved it for me.